# Perl non greedy expression

Tags: perl-module

I want to match following SQL statement:

```
insert into EMP  ( DATE ) values ( TO_DATE('05/13/2013 00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') );
```

with following expression:

```
TO_DATE\((.*)\)?
```

But its matching following:

```
TO_DATE('05/13/2013 00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') );
```

I want to only match following:

```
TO_DATE('05/13/2013 00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

What should the RE be?

Answer (score 0):

Try `TO_DATE\((.*?)\)?`

Adding `?` to `*` makes it non-greedy.

UPDATE

This should work: `/TO_DATE(\(.*?\))/`, this will include the first set of parentheses inside the capture group.

Comment: Got it, it should be:
TO_DATE\((.*?)\)